# Hide the "Smart querying activated" message in Jira

Tags: jira

Every time I do a search in Jira, this message pops up:

[image]

Now I want smart querying to be enabled, but I don't need this message **every time** I do a search, especially because it's placed on top of some buttons...

Is there any way to disable this?

Answer (score 1):

Seems there is no way to disable this, but it doesn't happen for every search. It only happens for certain keywords that trigger the smart querying capabilities. For example, a word that matches a status in JIRA (e.g. open, resolved).

A workaround is described in this JIRA issue:
https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRA-44561

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(window).load(function(){
 /*
   Hides the blank Announcement Banner div.
   If using an announcement banner already, 
   simply comment or remove the line below 
 */
 AJS.$("#announcement-banner").hide(); 

 /*
   If this page is the issue navigator and running a JQL query (not a filter)
   Checks if there is a "AUI Flag Container". If there is one and the text is
   "Smart querying activated", hides the banner.
 */
 if (window.location.pathname.includes("/issues/") && window.location.search.includes("?jql=")){
  test = AJS.$("#aui-flag-container")
  if (test.text().includes("Smart querying activated")) {
   AJS.$("#aui-flag-container").hide();
  }
 }
});
</script>
```

basically it runs some Javascript inserted into the (customisable) announcement banner.

Very annoying but as usual Atlassian said that they won't fix it.